# Definition of root and purely inseparable

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I have a problem with the definition of root and purely inseparable.

My book defines the purely inseparable iff 'the min($F,\alpha$) has only one distinct root'.

(1). How to define 'root' in Algebra? Does it mean '$\alpha$ is root of $f(x)$ in $K$, iff $f(\alpha)=0$'? Here$f(x)\in F[x]$ and $K$ in an extension of $F$. And I need to regard the $f(x)$ to be in $K[x]$.

(2). When I write $(x-\alpha)|f(x)$ , is it automatically assumed that $f(x)$ is in $K[x]$? And is it equivalent to say $\alpha$ is root of $f(x)$?

(3). For the definition of purely inseparable, does the author means that there is no other element in $K$ that making min$(F,\alpha)$ to be $0$ in the sense of (1)? ($K$ is not assumed to be splitting field).

These question seems silly, but I want to make sure...
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be a field. Then for each element $\alpha\in K$ we have the evaluation map $K[x]\to K$ which is $K$-linear and sends $x\mapsto\alpha$. We write $f(\alpha)$ for the image of a polynomial $f\in K[x]$.

We say that $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ provided $f(\alpha)=0$. By the division algorithm, this is equivalent to saying that $x-\alpha$ divides $f(x)$ in $K[x]$.

If now $F\subset K$ is a subfield, then we can regard $F[x]$ as a subring of $K[x]$, and the evaluation map restricts to a map $F[x]\to K$, which is $F$-linear and sends $x\mapsto\alpha$. Thus for $f\in F[x]$ we have $\alpha\in K$ is a root of $f$ provided $f(\alpha)=0$, or equivalently $x-\alpha$ divides $f(x)$ in $K[x]$.

That answers (1) and (2).

(3). You are correct that the definition from the book is a bit ambiguous. An algebraic element $\alpha\in K$ is purely inseparable over the subfield $F$ provided the minimal polynomial $m:=\mathrm{min}(F,\alpha)$ has only one root in *every* field extension of $K$. In this case it follows that $m=(x-\alpha)^d\in K[x]$ for some $d$, so that $m$ actually splits over $K$, and conversely if $m=(x-\alpha)^d\in K[x]$, then $\alpha$ is purely inseparable over $F$.

In summary, $\alpha\in K$ is purely inseparable over $F$ provided the minimal polynomial $\mathrm{min}(F,\alpha)$ factors as $(x-\alpha)^d$ in $K[x]$.

This is different to saying that $m$ has only the one root $\alpha$ in $K$, since it may not split over $K$. For example, let $\alpha=\sqrt[3]2\in\mathbb R$, and take $F=\mathbb Q$ and $K=\mathbb Q(\alpha)$. Then the minimal polynomial $m=x^3-2$ has only one root in $K$ but $\alpha$ is separable over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Emmmm, in the 3rd line of (3), do you mean that I can choose a splitting field S for $min(F)$ over K, then $m=(x-\alpha)^d\in S[x]$, but m itself in $K[x]$, so $m\in K[x]$?

Comment: And at last, why do you say $\alpha$ is separable over $Q$?? The complex field is also extension of $K$, but m has other two different roots in $C$...

Comment: For your first comment: if $m$ has only one root in _every_ field extension of $K$, then this necessarily holds for the splitting field $S$. Since $\alpha$ is a root, this is the only root, so $m=(x-\alpha)^d$ in $S[x]$. Since $\alpha\in K$, this factorisation already occurs over $K$, so $m=(x-\alpha)^d$ in $K[x]$.

Comment: For your second comment: $\alpha=\sqrt[3]2$ is separable over $\mathbb Q$. In characteristic zero every algebraic extension is separable. The example was just to show that to define purely inseparable, it is not enough to ask that $m$ has only one root in $K$, one needs to ask about all extensions of $K$.

Comment: Oh,,,I mistake 'separable' for 'inseparable'. I understand now. Thanks!